# How put additional `<tr>` (witl all attachments) in an existing table?

Tags: javascript

I have a table with some `<tr>` (containes post form with some `<td>` as input).   I want to add additional `<tr>` witl all attachments in table when pressed button.
How put additional `<tr>` (witl all attachments)  in an existing table?
In this additional field, I want to insert values and send only this form.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var prCon = document.getElementById("tab_prCon").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
    var row = prCon.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    cell1.innerHTML = "<td>" + 0 + "</td>";
    cell2.innerHTML = "<td class=\"col-xs-2\"><input name='login' type='text' placeholder='login' class='form-control'/> </td>";
    cell3.innerHTML = "<td class=\"col-xs-2\"><input name='password' type='text' placeholder='password' class='form-control'/></td>";
    cell4.innerHTML = "<td><button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-success btn-md\">Save</button>\n";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_prCon">
            <thead>
                <tr>                  
                    <th class="text-center">
                        #
                    </th>
                    <th class="text-center">
                        login
                    </th>
                    <th class="text-center">
                        password
                    </th>
                    <th class="text-center">
                        action
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr id="addrPrCon">
                   <form action="/login" method="post">
                       <td>1</td>
                       <td class="col-xs-2">
                          <input class="form-control" name="login" type="text" value="login">
                       </td>
                       <td class="col-xs-2">
                          <input class="form-control" name="password" type="text" value="pass">
                       </td>
                       <td>
                          <button class="btn btn-success btn-md" type="submit">Save</button>
                       </td>
                 </form>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <p>
            Click the button to create a TD element.
        </p><button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does jquery fine for you?

Comment: @Munkhdelger Tumenbayar  yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function formVal(value){
console.log(value);
}
function myFunction() {
    var prCon = document.getElementById("tab_prCon").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
    var row = prCon.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    cell1.innerHTML = "<td>" + 0 + "</td>";
    cell2.innerHTML = "<td class=\"col-xs-2\"><input name='login' type='text' placeholder='login' class='form-control'/> </td>";
    cell3.innerHTML = "<td class=\"col-xs-2\"><input name='password' type='text' placeholder='password' class='form-control'/></td>";
    cell4.innerHTML = "<td><button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-success btn-md\">Save</button>\n";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_prCon">
            <thead>
                <tr>                  
                    <th class="text-center">
                        #
                    </th>
                    <th class="text-center">
                        login
                    </th>
                    <th class="text-center">
                        password
                    </th>
                    <th class="text-center">
                        action
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr id="addrPrCon">
                   <form action="/login" method="post">
                   <table>
                       <td>1</td>
                       <td class="col-xs-2">
                          <input class="form-control" name="login" type="text" value="login">
                       </td>
                       <td class="col-xs-2">
                          <input class="form-control" name="password" type="text" value="pass">
                       </td>
                       <td>
                          <button class="btn btn-success btn-md" type="submit" onclick="formVal()">Save</button>
                       </td>
                       </table>
                 </form>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <p>
            Click the button to create a TD element.
        </p><button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you try this

```js
function myFunction() {
 var prCon = document.getElementById("tab_prCon").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
 var row = prCon.insertRow(-1);
 var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
 var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
 var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
 var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
 cell1.innerHTML = "<td>" + 0 + "</td>";
 cell2.innerHTML ="<td class=\"col-xs-2\"><input name='login' type='text' placeholder='login' class='form-control'/> </td>";
 cell3.innerHTML ="<td class=\"col-xs-2\"><input name='password' type='text' placeholder='password' class='form-control'/></td>";
 cell4.innerHTML ="<td><button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-success btn-md\">Save</button>\n";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_prCon">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th class="text-center">
      #
     </th>
     <th class="text-center">
      login
     </th>
     <th class="text-center">
      password
     </th>
     <th class="text-center">
      action
     </th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr id="addrPrCon">
     <td>
      <form action="/login" method="post">
       1
      </form>
     </td>
     <td class="col-xs-2">
      <input class="form-control" name="login" type="text" value="login">
     </td>
     <td class="col-xs-2">
      <input class="form-control" name="password" type="text" value="pass">
     </td>
     <td>
      <button class="btn btn-success btn-md" type="submit">Save</button>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
  <p>
   Click the button to create a TD element.
  </p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
 </body>
```

Comment: Check this answer click add it add 4 td with 1 row bottom

Comment: @ Munkhdelger Tumenbayar yore evample doesn't work for me; I  explained a bit more about the issue, check please

Answer (score 0):

Its not a good idea to make form as child element of table. Although you can insert the complete table inside form.
Try inserting a form inside `<tr id="addrPrCon">`, where you can insert all the td tags inside table

Comment: I changed `<tbody>` and `<form>` with `<td>` in `<tr>` now. In generall this default `<tr>` works, but I have a problem when I add `<tr>` accross script

Comment: @makson Can you please update your changes in the code snippet above and explain a bit more about the issue you are facing